# How find these lines in a prestashop page

Tags: prestashop

I know this is not a Prestashop forum but I have no luck there so I will try here where I normally get help.

I run version 1.6.1.6

The problem is the following. When a new customer register there is no field for a country. But when the customer for some reason needs to change address or add another one the form contains an obligatory field for a country, but the list is empty. It seems no one has found a solution so I wanted to solve the problem myself. We are a one country shop so the field is not necessary and I want to take it away. I have already put a default country id value in the database table

This is the div I want to find

```
<div class="required form-group">   <label for="id_country">Land <sup>*
</sup></label>   <select id="id_country" class="form-control"
name="id_country">       </select>   </div>
```

And this is the address to the page
    jv74.se/index.php?controller=address&id_address=5

Anyone have a clue where I should start

Answer (score 1):

Did you search in the file `controllers/front/AddressController.php` ?
I think you can override the method `assignCountries()` to send for `countries_list` only the country you want.

Comment: Could not find what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

This HTML/Smarty code is in `/themes/default-bootstrap/address.tpl`, and is populated at function `assignCountries()` from `/controllers/front/AddressController.php`